# how can to Import from deeper subfolder?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to import my `app` function which is inside front/app `__init__`, but somehow `from front.app import app` it doesnt work from `tooler.py`.

```
.
├── settings
│   ├── settings.json
├── front
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   └── demo.css
│   │   │   ├── data.json
│   │   │   └── js
│   │   │       └── script.js
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── public
│   │   │       └── index.html
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   └── run.py
├── tooler.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── utils.cpython-36.pyc
├── requirements.txt
├── tester.py
├── tree
└── utils.py
```

run.py

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**init**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import views
```

I expect the output of `running the server flask`, but the actual output is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: How can the same package be both `app` and `front.app`?  (Especially if this is Python 3, where relative imports must be explicit?)

Comment: I have no problem to import it in `tooler.py`. I would rather expect problem with `from app import views`. So better put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: it should be rather `from . import views` with dot instead `app`. And you can even put this before `app = Flask(__name__)`